# iOS 7 UITableView: is it a bug or is it me?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

Please see the attached image. In table views in iOS 7, UIKit draws a thin gray vertical line between the accessory view and the reordering control. However, when the table view is scrolled this line is not drawn in some cells. It is absent in cells 1, 2 and 8 in the attached image. Why is this? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: So you are not drawing this line? It isn't something in your `cellForRow...` implementation?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is: can you reproduce this issue in a plain vanilla minimal project that has nothing to do with your app? If so, it sounds like an iOS 7 bug. But if not, then it's something you are doing. :)

Comment: Yes I can reproduce this by simply modifying the following to boilerplate `UITableViewController` code to conditionally show an editingAccessoryType on certain cells. Something like `cell.editingAccessoryType = (indexPath.row % 2 ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`.  UIKit seems not to correctly update the vertical line decoration when the cell is reused in different row from before. Filing a bug.

Comment: Good info; I can reproduce the same way.

Comment: I can reproduce in the iOS 6.1 simulator as well.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple and it came back as a duplicate. So, they may not be fixing it, but they do know about it.

Comment: I am seeing this as well

Answer (score 6):

I'm having the same issue on an iphone 6s plus and solved it setting the backgroundColor of the cell's textLabel to clearColor

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Looking at my problem with [reveal](http://revealapp.com/) showed me that the right border of the label was drawing this vertical line.
[image]

Comment: This worked for me, but I also found that I could set the cell background color to clear in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this using

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView=nil;
}
```

this method might be helpful or something that might be in you cell like some image or what.?
or you can check that using allocation of cell like this
place if(cell==nil) instead if(1)and alloc cell eveytime

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to find a work-around. The problem seems to happen when the table view is in editing mode and dequeues a cell which was queued while the table view was in non-editing mode. The work-around is to set the editing property of the cell to NO immediately after dequeuing it.
The table view will set this property back to YES by itself after you return the cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.editing = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for Swift 2.1. on iOS 9.2.1. in XCode 7.2.:
I tested the code on iPhone 6s, while on 4" devices the separator does not appear.

I have made a subclass of `UITableViewCell`

Inside of `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` I have done this:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

You might find the need to set the background color in `override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {}` since this solution applies only to a cell create by Interface builder.

The solution works on dev and simulator.