# Table View Cell After Upgrading Project from XCODE 5.x to 6.x

Tags: uitableview, ios8

I'm getting an unusual line within the cell of my tableView after transitioning to XCODE 6.  My build target is set to 7.1.

Here is the image I'm getting:

[image]

The faint gray line is undesired, and I would like for it just to be a solid white background but cannot figure out what is causing the border-like line.

Can anyone suggest how I can get rid of this line?  (Wasn't there before moving to XCode 6, although the cells previously had gray horizontal separators that are now gone);

Any suggestion appreciated..

Comment: What are the elements in the cell? Is the 'v' an imageView? Also, can you please tell what do you mean by "cells previously had gray horizontal separators that are now gone"? Share some code if you like, i guess it will help... Maybe regarded to 'separatorInset' like that mentioned in other questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22572135/4151918